# Uploading via SSH with rsync and spawn

Tags: bash, ssh, expect, rsync, uploading

Until very recently I have been using the following bash script to upload any edited files to my server.

**./updatesite.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn rsync -av -e ssh "/(...)/webs" xusernamex@xdomainx.com:/home/webs
   expect "password:"
   send "xpasswordx\r"
   expect "*\r"
   expect "\r"
```

Usually it has worked fine.  For some reason it has abruptly stopped working several weeks ago.  Here is the output it now provides:

```
xuserx@xdomainx.com's password: 
building file list ... done
```

As you can see, No files are actually uploaded. But if I paste that exact same command directly into my terminal window without the "spawn," its behavior changes and it uploads the files as usual.

Here is an example:

```
Squid:~ John$ rsync -av -e ssh "/(...)/webs" xuserx@xdomainx.com:/home/xuserx
xuserx@xdomainx.com's password: 
building file list ... done
webs/somefile.txt

sent 878 bytes  received 42 bytes  204.44 bytes/sec
total size is 96409  speedup is 104.79
Squid:~ John$
```

Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: can you run SSH with debug option?  ssh -d xuserx@xdomainx.com, what's the output?

Comment: Does your configuration allow sftp (which is nothing to do with ftp) or scp instead of trying do non-interactive ssh?

Comment: @BradHards I'm afraid I am new to networking.  My server is hosted by Dreamhost, if that helps.  I seem to remember it supporting sftp, though.

Comment: OK. I think sftp might be a better option here. man sftp  might be useful to research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
# exp_internal 1    ;# uncomment to turn on expect debugging
set timeout -1
spawn rsync -av -e ssh "/(...)/webs" xusernamex@xdomainx.com:/home/webs
expect "password:"
send "xpasswordx\r"
expect eof
```

It may be a timeout issue, so set the timeout to infinite. Since you don't have to interact with rsync in any way except for the password, just wait for it to finish (expect eof).

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for the tip!